# How to get UTC time of my local time with "Z" at the end?

Tags: java, datetime-format, utc, time-format

I want to get current time in java in UTC:

So, I'm in Vienna now, the current local time is **16:30:29**, current offset to UTC is **2 hours** and I want to get

```
2022-05-27T14:30:29.813Z
```

with this Z at the end (indicating "Zulu time").

with this

```
public static String getIsoUtcDate() {
    Instant inst = Instant.now();
    return inst.toString();
}
```

I get

```
2022-05-27T14:30:29.813923100Z
```

How to get rid of microseconds?

I tried with `SimpleDateFormat` also, but with this I'm unable to get Z at the end.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat`? Please don't do that. That class is obsolete. Use `DateTimeFormatter` to format your dates and times.

Comment: `return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS))`

Comment: Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MILLIS).toString()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `OffsetDateTime` and set its offset to UTC. Then use a `DateTimeFormatter` to format it. Like this:

```
public static String getIsoUtcDate() {
    OffsetDateTime nowUtc = OffsetDateTime.now()
        .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

    return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.format(nowUtc);
}
```

Comment: NB: This answer is superior to the suggestion in the comments. An instant is at its core a moment-in-time, and has nothing to do with years, months, or seconds. The concept of `Instant` and the concept of `OffsetDateTime` starts becoming vague specifically when we speak of UTC, given that UTC cannot change (the difference in ODT/ZDT vs. Instant is that ODT/ZDT changes as locales switch timezones, Instant does not. But given that UTC never changes...) - nevertheless, given that you want it printed in terms of y/m/d/etc, This is the more readable, clearer way.

Comment: Great comment @rzwitserloot

Comment: I tried: With this solution I have again microseconds. i want see only millis

Comment: @MichaelW You need to use the `truncatedTo` method as shown in the other answer. It exists for both `Instant` and `OffsetDateTime` (and a number of other java.time classes). Alternatively use a formatter that prints only milliseconds (three decimals of fractional seconds).

Answer (score 1):

## `Instant#truncatedTo`

The [Answer by marstran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407219/642706) is more flexible. But for your particular case, there is a simpler way.

```
String output = 
    Instant
    .now()
    .truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MILLIS )
    .toString() 
;
```